Writing python function - I made a condition but it is wrong
The population of healthy people is equal to 150, while the population of sick people is equal to 120. Every day, 20% of healthy people get sick and 10% of sick people get healthy. Please write a function in the Python programming language that will calculate at what proportion of healthy and sick people equilibrium will be reached.
First I tried to do 2 mathematical equations
H - healthy
C - sick

H_1 = 0.8H + 0.1C
C_2 = 0.9C + 0.2H

H_1 = 120 + 12 = 132
H_2 = 108 + 30 = 138

132:138

22:23

At what ratio will the equilibrium remain? Could you please help me with writing that function?

What have you tried so far?  Please post your code.

Sure here :
def equilibrium_population(initial_healthy, initial_sick, iterations=1000):
healthy = initial_healthy
sick = initial_sick
for _ in range(iterations):
    new_healthy = 0.8 * healthy + 0.1 * sick
    new_sick = 0.9 * sick + 0.2 * healthy
    
    if abs(new_healthy - healthy) < 0.001 and abs(new_sick - sick) < 0.001:
        break
    
    healthy, sick = new_healthy, new_sick

equilibrium_proportion = new_healthy / (new_healthy + new_sick)
return equilibrium_proportion, new_healthy, new_sick


initial_healthy = 150
initial_sick = 120
equilibrium_proportion, new_healthy, new_sick = equilibrium_population(initial_healthy, initial_sick)
print("Proportion of healthy people at equilibrium:", equilibrium_proportion)
print("Number of healthy people at equilibrium:", new_healthy)
print("Number of sick people at equilibrium:", new_sick)

@kate_washington please [edit] your Question to include that!

I'm confused why the initial values of H = 150 and C = 120 are even given. the stable point can be computed without running a simulation

Equilibrium 0.2H=0.1S, so rearrange for H/S. The answer is mildly surprising. But so was Covid.

you can try this
h = 150
s = 120

get_h = 0.1 #10% will get healthy
get_s = 0.2 #20% will get healthy

proportion_h = 150 / (150+120) #first proportion

delta = 1 #diffirence

while delta != 0:
    got_sick = h*get_s
    got_healthy = s*get_h
    h = int(h - got_sick + got_healthy)
    s = int(s - got_healthy + got_sick)
    
    delta = proportion_h - h /(h+s)
    proportion_h = h /(h+s) 
    proportion_s = 1-proportion_h

print(f'healthy : {h} , sick : {s}, proportion_h : {proportion_h*100}%,proportion_s : {proportion_s*100}%')


this is the result of this function: healthy : 86 , sick : 172, proportion_h : 33.33333333333333%, proportion_s : 66.66666666666667%.
Why when 1/3 of population is healthy and 2/3 is sick there is balance?

There is “balance” because these numbers won’t change at the next iteration. Hence, equilibrium.

As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers in the help center.

To solve this problem we can make an array that contain n rows (number of iteration until reach to the balance  where each rows contain:

n : iteration number (row number)
h : The population of healthy people
c : the population of sick people
err: Error value

We define a function to make this array called nhce
def nhce(h,c):
    i=[[0,h,c,None]]
    n=0
    while i[n][3]!=0:
        i.append([n:=i[n][0]+1, x:=round(0.8*i[n-1][1]+0.1*i[n-1][2]), y:=round(0.2*i[n-1][1]+0.9*i[n-1][2]),err:=(i[n-1][1]-x)**2+(i[n-1][2]-y)**2 ])
    return i

As we see this function will return an array and we can use it as below:
arr=nhce(150,120)
print(arr)

Result:

[[0, 150, 120, None], [1, 132, 138, 648], [2, 119, 151, 338], [3,
110, 160, 162], [4, 104, 166, 72], [5, 100, 170, 32], [6, 97, 173,
18], [7, 95, 175, 8], [8, 94, 176, 2], [9, 93, 177, 2], [10, 92, 178,
2], [11, 91, 179, 2], [12, 91, 179, 0]]

arr=nhce(150,120)
print("Equilibrium remain at {}:{} in iteration number {} ".format(arr[len(arr)-1][1],arr[len(arr)-1][2],arr[len(arr)-1][0]))

Result:

Equilibrium remain at 91:179 in iteration number 12

